# how to compare two csv file in python and flag the difference?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, export-to-csv

i am new to python. Kindly help me.
Here I have two set of csv-files. i need to compare and output the difference like changed data/deleted data/added data. here's my example

```
file 1:
Sn  Name  Subject   Marks  
1   Ram      Maths     85
2   sita    Engilsh    66
3   vishnu  science    50
4   balaji  social     60

file 2:
Sn  Name    Subject   Marks
1   Ram     computer  85   #subject name have changed
2   sita    Engilsh   66
3   vishnu  science   90   #marks have changed
4   balaji  social    60
5   kishor  chem      99   #added new line

Output - i need to get like this :

Changed Items: 
1   Ram      computer  85
3   vishnu    science  90
Added item:
5   kishor    chem   99
Deleted item:
.................
```

I imported csv and done the comparasion via for loop with redlines. I am not getting the desire output.  **its confusing me a lot when flagging the added  & deleted items between file 1 & file2 (csv files).** pl suggest the effective code folks.

Comment: What is the key to compare dataframes? `Sn` or `Name`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea here is to flatten your dataframe with `melt` to compare each value:

```
# Load your csv files
df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', ...)
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv', ...)

# Select columns (not mandatory, it depends on your 'Sn' column)
cols = ['Name', 'Subject', 'Marks']

# Flat your dataframes
out1 = df1[cols].melt('Name', var_name='Item', value_name='Old')
out2 = df2[cols].melt('Name', var_name='Item', value_name='New')
out = pd.merge(out1, out2, on=['Name', 'Item'], how='outer')

# Flag the state of each item
condlist = [out['Old'] != out['New'],
            out['Old'].isna(),
            out['New'].isna()]

out['State'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist=['changed', 'added', 'deleted'], 
                         default='unchanged')
```

Output:

```
>>> out
     Name     Item      Old       New      State
0     Ram  Subject    Maths  computer    changed
1    sita  Subject  Engilsh   Engilsh  unchanged
2  vishnu  Subject  science   science  unchanged
3  balaji  Subject   social    social  unchanged
4     Ram    Marks       85        85  unchanged
5    sita    Marks       66        66  unchanged
6  vishnu    Marks       50        90    changed
7  balaji    Marks       60        60  unchanged
8  kishor  Subject      NaN      chem    changed
9  kishor    Marks      NaN        99    changed
```

Comment: **I ran this code by importing with pandas but i am facing this error**

`File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 801, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read_low_memory
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 857, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 843, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1925, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 18 fields in line 3, saw 28`

Comment: initially i **print(df1)** but its throughing this above issue
it seems that **its not even starts to read my csv file**

Comment: How do you load your files? How many records do you have?

Comment: **it has 600 rows with 15 to 20 colums (in csv formate)**
`import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv')`

Answer (score 0):

```
count, flag = 0, 1
for i, j in zip(df1.values, df2.values):
    if sum(i == j) != 4:
        if flag:
            print("Changed Items:")
            flag = 0
        print(j)
    count += 1

if count != len(df2):
    print("Newly added:")
    print(*df2.iloc[count:, :].values)
```

[image]

Comment: **I ran this code by importing with pandas but i am facing this error**

`File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 801, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read_low_memory
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 857, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 843, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1925, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 18 fields in line 3, saw 28`

Comment: initially i **print(df1)** but its throughing this above issue
it seems that **its not even starts to read my csv file**

Comment: - import pandas and pd.read_csv(filename)
- then you got df1 & df2, so can you proceed further

Comment: yes as u mentioned i used that only
**it has 600 rows with 15 to 20 colums (in csv formate)**
`import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv')` same error as mentioned above

Comment: If two files with different no. of columns, then I think this cuases this problem.

My above mentioned code 3 no line ```if sum(i == j) != 4:```

here 4 is the column number according to your given sample data